# Dynamically setting ActionBar drop down navigation

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.actionOptions, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if(hours<6)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        else if(hours>=21)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(itemPosition){
                case 0:
                    isMode = "dMode";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    isMode = "nMode";
                    break;
                default:
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

In the following code, I am trying to set the drop down in the action bar according to the time of day. If it is from between 9pm to 6 pm Mode A is set otherwise Mode B is set. According to the default definition, Mode A is set at index position 1 and Mode B at 2. But the code does not seem to work. Help please. And i did try the code without the `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`. It just does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the adapter to the actionbar.

Like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter , this);
```

So the action bar knows what to actually display in the list.

Besides you also need to set the title to false

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Plus for the adapter you should use the right context:

```
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
```

and thus

```
 SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.actionOptions, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

Comment: i already did do that ... looks like i forgot to type it in. could you please see the edited question

Comment: see changed answer. Did you set the title to false?

Comment: A good example on how to implement this would be Andlytics:  https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics/blob/master/src/com/github/andlyticsproject/Main.java#L344